# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name defined in file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, javabeans, illegalstateexception

I use jdk-19 and try to run my application. All other classes, that have the same architecture work, except for this one.

**The model:**

```
package ch.ps_backend.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "addiction", schema = "ps_default")
public class Addiction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

}
```

**DTO**

```
package ch.ps_backend.dto;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * A DTO for the {@link ch.ps_backend.model.Addiction} entity
 */
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AddictionDto implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public AddictionDto(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof AddictionDto;
    }

}
```

**Mapper**

```
package ch.ps_backend.mapper;

import ch.ps_backend.dto.AddictionDto;
import ch.ps_backend.model.Addiction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AddictionMapper {

    public final Addiction FromDTO(AddictionDto dto) {
        Addiction entity = new Addiction();
        entity.setId(dto.getId());
        entity.setName(dto.getName());
        return entity;
    }

    public final AddictionDto ToDTO(Addiction entity) {
        AddictionDto dto = new AddictionDto();
        dto.setId(entity.getId());
        dto.setName(entity.getName());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package ch.ps_backend.repository;

import ch.ps_backend.model.Addiction;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface AddictionRepository extends JpaRepository<Addiction, Integer> {
    Addiction getById(int id);
}
```

**Service**

```
package ch.ps_backend.service;

import ch.ps_backend.dto.AddictionDto;
import ch.ps_backend.mapper.AddictionMapper;
import ch.ps_backend.repository.AddictionRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AddictionService {

    private final AddictionRepository addictionRepository;
    private final AddictionMapper addictionMapper;

    public AddictionService(AddictionRepository addictionRepository, AddictionMapper addictionMapper) {
        this.addictionRepository = addictionRepository;
        this.addictionMapper = addictionMapper;
    }

     public List<AddictionDto> getAll() {
         List<AddictionDto> tempAddiction = new ArrayList<>();
        addictionRepository.findAll().forEach(addiction -> {
            tempAddiction.add(addictionMapper.ToDTO(addiction));
        });
        return tempAddiction;
     }

    public AddictionDto getById(int id) {
        return addictionMapper.ToDTO(addictionRepository.getById(id));
    }
    public void createOrUpdateAddiction(AddictionDto addictionDto) {
        addictionRepository.save(addictionMapper.FromDTO(addictionDto));
    }

    public void deleteById(int id) {
        addictionRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package ch.ps_backend.controller;

import ch.ps_backend.dto.AddictionDto;
import ch.ps_backend.model.Addiction;
import ch.ps_backend.service.AddictionService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You do not have permission to do this. Please use /login first.",
                content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json")})})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/addictions")
public class AddictionController {

    private final AddictionService addictionService;

    public AddictionController(AddictionService addictionService) {
        this.addictionService = addictionService;
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Find all addictions.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addictions found",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})})
    @GetMapping
    public List<AddictionDto> findAll() {
        return addictionService.getAll();
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Find a addiction by its id")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction found",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Addiction not found",
                    content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})
    })
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public AddictionDto findById(@Parameter(description = "Id of addiction to get") @PathVariable Integer id) {
        try {
            return addictionService.getById(id);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Addiction could not be deleted");
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Create a new addiction.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Addiction was created successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})
    })
    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@Parameter(description = "The new addiction to create") @Valid @RequestBody AddictionDto newAddiction) {
        try {
            addictionService.createOrUpdateAddiction(newAddiction);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Update a addiction")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction was updated successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))})
    })
    @PutMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public void update(@Parameter(description = "The addiction to update") @Valid @RequestBody AddictionDto addiction) {
        try {
            addictionService.createOrUpdateAddiction(addiction);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Delete a addiction")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction was deleted successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Addiction could not be deleted",
                    content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))})
    })
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(@Parameter(description = "Id of addiction to delete") @PathVariable Integer id) {
        try {
            addictionService.deleteById(id);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Addiction could not be deleted");
        }
    }
}
package ch.ps_backend.controller;

import ch.ps_backend.dto.AddictionDto;
import ch.ps_backend.model.Addiction;
import ch.ps_backend.service.AddictionService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You do not have permission to do this. Please use /login first.",
                content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json")})})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/addictions")
public class AddictionController {

    private final AddictionService addictionService;

    public AddictionController(AddictionService addictionService) {
        this.addictionService = addictionService;
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Find all addictions.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addictions found",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})})
    @GetMapping
    public List<AddictionDto> findAll() {
        return addictionService.getAll();
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Find a addiction by its id")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction found",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Addiction not found",
                    content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})
    })
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public AddictionDto findById(@Parameter(description = "Id of addiction to get") @PathVariable Integer id) {
        try {
            return addictionService.getById(id);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Addiction could not be deleted");
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Create a new addiction.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Addiction was created successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = AddictionDto.class))})
    })
    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@Parameter(description = "The new addiction to create") @Valid @RequestBody AddictionDto newAddiction) {
        try {
            addictionService.createOrUpdateAddiction(newAddiction);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Update a addiction")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction was updated successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))})
    })
    @PutMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public void update(@Parameter(description = "The addiction to update") @Valid @RequestBody AddictionDto addiction) {
        try {
            addictionService.createOrUpdateAddiction(addiction);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }


    @Operation(summary = "Delete a addiction")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Addiction was deleted successfully",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Addiction could not be deleted",
                    content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation failed",
                    content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Addiction.class))})
    })
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(@Parameter(description = "Id of addiction to delete") @PathVariable Integer id) {
        try {
            addictionService.deleteById(id);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Addiction could not be deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't mind the swagger Documentation and the name of the table. I just need to fix that error somehow.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addictionController' defined in file [C:\Users\hofer\OneDrive\Dokumente\Parasys\ps_backend\target\classes\ch\ps_backend\controller\AddictionController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addictionService' defined in file [C:\Users\hofer\OneDrive\Dokumente\Parasys\ps_backend\target\classes\ch\ps_backend\service\AddictionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ch.ps_backend.repository.AddictionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addictionService' defined in file [C:\Users\hofer\OneDrive\Dokumente\Parasys\ps_backend\target\classes\ch\ps_backend\service\AddictionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ch.ps_backend.repository.AddictionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ch.ps_backend.repository.AddictionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I tried to build the app with maven clean install. It didn't work. I had to fix multiple issues, but they were easy and I found some helpful information. But now this error occured and i am very frustrated. I just want to know why and how to fix it.

**The pom.xml**
`

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

</parent>

<groupId>com.ps_backend</groupId>
<artifactId>ps_backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ps_backend</name>
<description>ps_backend</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>19</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>ch.ps_backend.ApiApplication</mainClass>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.12.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/parasys</url>
                <user>postgres</user>
                <password>1234</password>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>ps_default</schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have  \@EnableJpaRepositories on your \@Configuration class?

Comment: Also you can add @Repository on class level for `AddictionRepository`

Comment: Which version of Spring boot you're using?
Which swagger version?

Comment: @tgdavies
Do you mean this:
\@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
\@SpringBootApplication
public class PsBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PsBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Comment: @ЕмилиянЙорданов I tried.. it didn't work :/

Comment: @SomeoneNewThatHasNoIdea can we see the application / configuration class where you have things @EnableXxxxxx annotations? I think @tgdavies is probably right that you're missing and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on it